# Apache Ignite analogue of Spark vector UDF and distributed compute in general

Tags: ignite

I have been using Spark for some time now with success in Python however we have a product written in C# that would greatly benefit from distributed and parallel execution. I did some research and tried out the new C# API for Spark but this is a little restrictive at the moment.

In regards to Ignite, on the surface it seems like a decent alternative. Its got good .NET support, it has clustering ability and the ability to distribute compute across the grid.

However, I was wondering if it really can be used to replace Spark in our use case - what we need is a distributed way in which to perform data frame type operations. In particular a lot of our code in Python was implemented using Pandas UDF and we let Spark worry about the data transfer and merging of results.

If i wanted to use Ignite, where our data is really more like a table (typically CSV sourced) rather than key/value based, is there an efficient way to represent that data across the grid and send computations to the cluster that execute on an arbitrary subset of the data in the same way Spark does, especially in the sense that the result of the calculations just become 1..n more columns in the dataframe without having to collect all the results back to the main program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your structured data (CSV) to Ignite using its SQL implementation:

https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/overview

it will provide the possibility to do distributed SQL queries over this data and indexes support. Spark also provides the possibility to work with structured data using SQL but there are no indexes. Indexes will help you to significantly increase the performance of your SQL operations.

In case if you have already had some solution worked using Spark data frames then you also can save the same logic but use Ignite integration with Spark instead:

https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-data-frame

In this case, you can have all data stored in Ignite SQL tables and do SQL requests and other operations using Spark.

Here you can see an example how to load CSV data to Ignite using Spark DF and how it can be configured:

https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/how-debug-data-loading-spark-ignite